# setting width and height of image in codeigniter php not working

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter website where user can upload multiple images, i want all the images to be of the same size, i have done the following code in controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['addblog'])) {
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $image = array();
    $ImageCount = count($_FILES['image_name']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $ImageCount; $i++) {
        $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['image_name']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['image_name']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['image_name']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['image_name']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['image_name']['size'][$i];

        $uploadPath = './uploads/blog/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['width'] = 200;
        $config['height'] = 250;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {

            $imageData = $this->upload->data();

            $uploadImgData[] = $imageData['file_name'];
        }
    }
    $blogimage = $uploadImgData;
}
```

as u can see i have set the height and width in config, the images are still uploaded in ther original size, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has just made a little mistake in your config :

```
$config['max_width'] = 200; 
$config['max_height'] = 250;
```

Sadly "min_width" and  "min_height" seems doesn't exist yet

Comment: i get this error Message: Undefined variable: uploadImgData

Comment: you declare and use "uploadImgData" in the same place,try to create the variable before your loop just after $imageCount. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['width'] = 200;
$config['height'] = 250;
```

Replace With

```
$config['max_width'] = /*Your Need */;
$config['max_height'] = /*Your Need */;
```